# Can't connect to Nginx webserver on LAN

Tags: pi-2, web-server, nginx

I cant connect to my Nginx web server when on my LAN, I have tried using both the internal and external IP's to do this I keep getting told connection refused. By this I mean that if I try to connect via web browser chrome/edge I get a connection refused page, furthermore when attempting to download index.php I get connection refused. Ping requests time out both when inside the network and outside. The site is definitely up http://http//www.isitdownrightnow.com/tasty.zapto.org.html. The site-specific Nginx config is here

Comment: Hi @Tasty213, welcome :) But you give us very little information to help you. Do you tried in a browser to connect to the web server with `http://`? What is the internal and external ip address? It seems there is a problem with configuration of `Nginx` and nothing specific to Raspberry Pi. If so, please ask on our sister site https://superuser.com/users/879258/ingo

Comment: pi internal ip: 192.168.1.9

Comment: pi external ip: 87.112.59.181 (defo up checked with http://http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/tasty.zapto.org.html)

Comment: have tried connecting with chrome and edge, both gives a connection refused, same with wget command on a Linux terminal.

Comment: nginx config for site
https://hastebin.com/sijilidise.nginx

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "can't connect" means.  There are three possibilities and it is possible to distinguish between them based on what a web browser says.  Also, you could cut and paste the output of `ping` into the question.

Comment: By can't connect i mean that when i type the URL (or up internal/external) into the address bar i get connection refused same from a wget command ping request timed out (although that's the same when connecting from outside) note i can connect by VPN even when inside network and i have tried from multiple devices

Comment: "Connection refused" indicates nothing is listening on the port.  Try `lsof -i TCP:80` (presuming you are using the normal http port; if you are using https, the normal port is 443); if this shows that nginx *is* on the port, then the IP address is wrong.  There are not any possibilities beyond this.

Comment: Listening on both TCP 80 and TCP 443  both root and www-data accounts. (But not listening on UDP)

Comment: So wich IP address would be wrong?

Comment: This might be related to nginx listening to a specific address (hostname) which doesn't resolve from the network. Try editing the second line of your config file, to `listen 192.168.1.9:80 default_server;`. If that works, make the same edit for SSL on line 8, though you may face further problems with your SSL certificates in that case. You might instead add your hostname to the hosts file of the machine you're accessing the site from (in Linux, append `tasty.zapto.org` to `/etc/hosts`), and try access it via the hostname.

Comment: Ok now I've got an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOOL_ERROR
will try regenerating SSL certificates